# How is "lassen" used in the context of this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, verb

> Könnten Sie mein Gepäck bitte herunterbringen lassen?

How does usage of *lassen* work here?

Can anybody please give more examples of *lassen* similar to this one.

Normally it means *leave*.

Comment: dict.cc gives `to let` as the first translation

Comment: _Lassen_ does not normally mean 'to leave', you may be thinking of _verlassen_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=lassen) gives *to have sth done* as the second but last translation.

This exactly reflects the usage of *lassen* in this context.

The translation of your example would be as follows:

> Could you please have my luggage brought down (to the entrance hall)?

one could also translate using *to let*:

> Could you please let the luggage be brought down?

Further examples:

> Lassen Sie den Wagen vorfahren.
>   Lassen Sie das Essen bringen.
>   Könnten Sie bitte den Champagner auf das Zimmer bringen lassen?

In this context *"lassen"* will be used with an action of a third party. 
The first party is the "requester". He asks the second party, the "middleman" to give the third party, the "requested", instructions on something to be done in a certain way. Sometimes second and third party are the same person, but that is rather unusual.

You might hear this construction in a 5 stars hotel, like 'Ritz', when a guest asks the concierge for something to be done.