# "Verb" or "verb + lassen"? How to know when does a verb need "lassen"?

Tags: grammar, verb, single-word-request

I thought I understood what a `Verb` and a `Verb` + *lassen* mean (somehow influenced by [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7241/how-is-lassen-used-in-the-context-of-this-sentence)), but I don't. My previous idea was that one writes `Verb` + *lassen* when the action is not performed by the subject, but by third agents:

> Karl lässt sich die Haare schneiden.

But I heard the expression

> Ich würde mich trennen lassen.

in the context of getting divorced. The subject decides that he/she wants the divorce. Why does one use *lassen*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd rather suggest "Ich würde mich (von ihm/ihr) trennen" and "Ich würde mich (von ihm/ihr) scheiden lassen", and indeed for the reason you suspect: A Trennung is typically executed by the persons themselves, a Scheidung is an act done by a judge (even though this happens per request of at least one of the partners - but that would also apply to the barber's)

Comment: ach so? dann es war nicht `trennen`, sondern `scheiden`.